# Does the Bluetooth Low Energy notification wakes up the CPU?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-wake-lock

Let's say I have an Android app which connects to a BLE device. The app uses a foreground service in order to constantly receive the BLE notifications on characteristic change. Will the phone receive and process the notification when it's in sleep mode (Doze)? Or should I keep CPU WAKE LOCK all the time?

Comment: foreground services are not affected when doze kicks in

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, foreground services are not affected by Doze, but it doesn't mean that the CPU will still be running after the user turns off the screen.

Comment: For example, on developer.android.com I read "One remaining use-case for partial wake locks is to ensure that a music app continues to play when the screen is off". And also "If you must use partial wake locks, follow these recommendations:

Make sure some portion of your app remains in the foreground. For example, if you need to run a service, start a foreground service instead. This visually indicates to the user that your app is still running"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're fine if you have a Foreground Service. The arrival of a Bluetooth packet will wake up the CPU.